# What are the similarities and differences between MongoDB's mapreduce and Hadoop?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

Besides the similarity in the use of a map and reduce function. For example does MongoDB apply a combine function?

Comment: There would be a lot of similarities between Hadoop and MongoDB MapReduce, so the better query would be about the difference. The main difference I see is the [incremental MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-IncrementalMapreduce). In Hadoop, the reducers won't start processing the data until maps are done with the processing, which is not the case with MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread answers your question: [Hadoop Map/Reduce vs built-In Map/Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287585/hadoop-map-reduce-vs-built-in-map-reduce)

You might also be interested in this post on analyzing a large number of documents using MongoDB mapReduce: http://steveeichert.com/2010/03/31/data-analysis-using-mongodb-map-reduce.html/