# What is an efficient way to send data from MongoDB to Hadoop?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I was discussing with a coworker about the usage of the MongoDB connector for Hadoop and he explained that it was very inefficient. He stated that the MongoDB connectors utilizes its own map reduce, and then uses the Hadoop map reduce, which internally slows down the entire system.

If that is the case, what is the most efficient way to transport my data to the Hadoop cluster? What purpose does the MongoDB connector serve if it is more inefficient? In my scenario, I want to get the daily inserted data from MongoDB (roughly around 10MB) and put that all into Hadoop. I should also add that each MongoDB node and Hadoop node all share the same server.

Comment: When your Hadoop node and your MongoDB node run on the same hardware anyway, why do you worry about which one executes the MapReduce?

Comment: @Philipp This is all relatively new to me, but what my coworker was telling me was that MongoDB's MapReduce differs from Hadoop's version. And MongoDB's was a lot slower.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is some validity to his brief based on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287585/hadoop-map-reduce-vs-built-in-map-reduce. But I just question whether or not the connector itself is inefficient.

Comment: Did you test it and measure the time? When you didn't, it's just hearsay.

Comment: Well, I have the connector working. I'm not really sure how to send the data over without it, as all this is still new to me. That's why I just want to check if everything I am learning theoretically makes sense. Otherwise, I won't really know if I am doing something wrong or if everything I did is working as intended.

Comment: The comparison of Map/Reduce engines does not suggest that both would be used in order to get data from MongoDB into Hadoop :). There are differences in the Map/Reduce implementations, and while Hadoop is generally more suitable for a large amount of data it also has a larger footprint and can be overkill if your data set is only MBs or GBs of data. See [To Hadoop or Not to Hadoop](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/hadoop-or-not-hadoop). There are other aggregation patterns such as incremental map/reduce or preaggregation that can reduce the size of data being processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MongoDB Connector for Hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) reads data directly from MongoDB.  You can configure multiple [input splits](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/CONFIG.md#mongoinputsplitcreate_input_splits) to read data from the same collection in parallel. The Mapper and Reducer jobs are run by Hadoop's Map/Reduce engine, not MongoDB's Map/Reduce.

If your data estimate is correct (only 10MB per day?) that is a small amount to ingest and the job may be faster if you don't have any input splits calculated.

You should be wary of Hadoop and MongoDB competing for resources on the same server, as contention for memory or disk can affect the efficiency of your data transfer.

Comment: I don't understand why my coworker says the data has to go through Map Reduce twice, from MongoDB and Hadoop. Is he totally off or is this also some kind of common practice? I kind of suspect that he has no idea what he is doing (as it has happened in the past).

Comment: Clearly a misunderstanding on how the integration works. It doesn't make sense to run through the same Map/Reduce process twice (once on MongoDB and again on Hadoop). If the data is already reduced, there would be nothing for the second M/R to do anyway :). If you are using Hadoop as the data processing engine, MongoDB's role via the Hadoop Connector is as a data input or output source: "The MongoDB Connector for Hadoop is a library which allows MongoDB (or backup files in its data format, BSON) to be used as an input source, or output destination, for Hadoop MapReduce tasks".

Comment: If you don't mind, I do have more question. Apparently the amount of data being processed averages to around 10-50 GB per day. After explaining why Hadoop is bad for this, my coworker suggests the usage of Twitter's Storm. Is Storm suited for this? I'd naturally assume it isn't because it is labeled as realtime Hadoop, but I don't really see any articles saying it is inefficient for smaller amounts of data.

Comment: What works best for real time data processing around 10 - 50 GB?

Answer (score 0):

To transfer your data from Mongodb to Hadoop you can use some **ETL tools** like Talend or Pentaho , it's much more easy and practical ! Good luck !